# error: package org.picketlink.idm.internal does not exist

Tags: java, maven

I changed my pom.xml to add picktlink-social so I changed my pom to remove picketlink-deltaspike, and addeda apache deltaspike because I had some redundancy issues with picktlink detlaspike, and for a while my app worked.

So every once in a while when I did a mvn clean, I got this error

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project unikaimagen: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/jdc/git/unikaimagen/src/main/java/ec/com/unikaimagen/init/IDMConfiguration.java:[33,34] error: package org.picketlink.idm.internal does not exist
[ERROR] /home/jdc/git/unikaimagen/src/main/java/ec/com/unikaimagen/init/IDMConfiguration.java:[35,30] error: package org.picketlink.internal does not exist
[ERROR] /home/jdc/git/unikaimagen/src/main/java/ec/com/unikaimagen/init/IDMConfiguration.java:[70,9] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class EEJPAContextInitializer
[ERROR] location: class IDMConfiguration
[ERROR] /home/jdc/git/unikaimagen/src/main/java/ec/com/unikaimagen/init/IDMConfiguration.java:[33,34] error: package org.picketlink.idm.internal does not exist
[ERROR] /home/jdc/git/unikaimagen/src/main/java/ec/com/unikaimagen/init/IDMConfiguration.java:[35,30] error: package org.picketlink.internal does not exist
[ERROR] /home/jdc/git/unikaimagen/src/main/java/ec/com/unikaimagen/init/IDMConfiguration.java:[70,9] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class EEJPAContextInitializer
[ERROR] location: class IDMConfiguration
[ERROR] /home/jdc/git/unikaimagen/src/main/java/ec/com/unikaimagen/init/IDMConfiguration.java:[110,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

So I changed the version of picketlink from 2.6.1 to 2.6.0 or 2.6.0 to 2.6.1 and it compiled again.  But now that is not even working,

This is my pom.xml http://pastebin.com/9bRMrGkv.

org.picketlink.internal should be in picketlink-impl module, which is included in my pom.xml

This is my IDMConfiguration.java http://pastebin.com/XES0WyDQ

http://pastebin.com/XES0WyDQ

I did a jarscan and found this

```
$ java -jar jarscan.jar -d /home/jdc/.m2/repository/ EEJPAContextInitializer
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
+/home/jdc/.m2/repository/org/picketlink/picketlink-impl/2.6.0.Final/picketlink-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar
    /home/jdc/.m2/repository/org/picketlink/picketlink-impl/2.6.0.Final/picketlink-impl-2.6.0.Final.jar/org/picketlink/internal/EEJPAContextInitializer.class
+/home/jdc/.m2/repository/org/picketlink/picketlink-impl/2.6.0.CR2/picketlink-impl-2.6.0.CR2.jar
    /home/jdc/.m2/repository/org/picketlink/picketlink-impl/2.6.0.CR2/picketlink-impl-2.6.0.CR2.jar/org/picketlink/internal/EEJPAContextInitializer.class
+/home/jdc/.m2/repository/org/picketlink/picketlink-impl/2.6.1.Final/picketlink-impl-2.6.1.Final.jar
    /home/jdc/.m2/repository/org/picketlink/picketlink-impl/2.6.1.Final/picketlink-impl-2.6.1.Final.jar/org/picketlink/internal/EEJPAContextInitializer.class
----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I updated the picketlink version. I checked your pom and I realized that it contains

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
    <artifactId>picketlink-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

which specifies all the dependencies, but you have also added each module separately. So, I think you should delete them and try again.